# jQuery sizzle error / disabling rails turbolinks on specific links? (jsFiddle included)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Setting  `data-no-turbolink="true"` in my a tag has absolutely no effect.

My HTML template looks essentially like this:

```
<fieldset id="1">
<h3>ONE</h3>
<a data-no-turbolink="true" href="#2" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >Next</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="2">
<h3>TWO</h3>
<a data-no-turbolink="true" href="#1" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >Back</a><br>
<a data-no-turbolink="true" href="#3" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >Next</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset  id="3">
<h3>THREE</h3>
<a data-no-turbolink="true" href="#2" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >Back</a><br>
<a data-no-turbolink="true" href="#4" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >Next</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset  id="4">
<h3>FOUR</h3>
<a data-no-turbolink="true" href="#3" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >Back</a>
</fieldset>
```

Simple JS:

```
  $(function() {
    $('fieldset').first().show();

    function change_fieldset(show_set) {
      $('fieldset').hide();
      $(show_set).show();
    }

    $('fieldset').on('click', 'a', function() {
      var show_set = $(this).attr('href');
      change_fieldset(show_set);
    });
  });
```

TurboLinks is breaking the code. I see this in console:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/people/1015/edit". turbolinks.js?body=1:87
```

And sometimes this happens:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost:3000/people/1015/edit#about-me-continued jquery.js?body=1:1472

Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

Here is a fiddle: (which works perfectly) http://jsfiddle.net/S8JkE/

Does anyone know why these random errors are happening? How to correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the value of `show_set` was randomly becoming the entire URL string which would cause the *Sizzle.error* I corrected the problem by changing `fieldset`'s to data-selectors and verifying the value of `show_set` before calling `show()` on it.

Working code:

```
  $(function() {
    $('fieldset').first().show();

    function change_fieldset(show_set) {
      $('fieldset').hide();
      $("[data-link="+show_set.replace(/.*#/,'')+"]").show();
    }

    $('fieldset').on('click', 'a', function() {
      var show_set = $(this).attr('href');
      change_fieldset(show_set);
    });
  });
```